# Admob and Geolocation combination not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, geolocation, admob

**I am working on Ionic1 Project which accessing user location,address etc. So we are using Geolocation plugin.(cordova-plugin-geolocation)
and Now i am trying to integrate Admob in my project, But its not working.(cordova-plugin-admob-free)**

Below are plugins which iam using in my project:

> Admob - "cordova-plugin-admob-free": "^0.23.0",
>   Geolocation -"cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.1",
>                "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy":
>                "cordova-admob-sdk": "^0.21.0",
>                "cordova-android": "7.0.0",

**I am getting below error when i run cordova build android**

**> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> What went wrong: Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'. BUILD FAILED in 2m 36s
>   (node:6836) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections
>   are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled
>   will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.**

Can you please let us know how to fix this?
If i remove geolocation plugin, app working fine.
But if two plugins are there in project its not working

Thank you[image]

Comment: I'm confused - the Admob plugin you're referring to does not need the geolocation plugin nor does it mention that anywhere in the documentation https://github.com/ratson/cordova-plugin-admob-free. Do you need the geolocation plugin for something else?

Comment: try remove plugin and add again

Comment: Kody R : Simple Just create 1. one project and integrate Geolocation plugin
               2. Try to integrate admob plugin to this project and run. you will get errors

Comment: proofzy : I have tried many times and cleaned project and downgraded to versions also but not working